# Laravel Laracast call to a member function connection() on null

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-artisan

How can I debug this error guys? This is the only error message I got in my terminal. This is existing project. I just clone this and tried to run it but encounter this issue.

**error:-**
[image]

```
APP_NAME=PalletConnect
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=magento2
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Here's the error log

> [2020-10-11 02:25:48] local.ERROR: Call to a member function
> connection() on null {"exception":"[object]
> (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0):
> Call to a member function connection() on null at
> /home/dc/Documents/Projects/PalletConnect/Warehouse%20Management%20Systems%20%28WMS%29/v1/api_v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1253)
> [stacktrace]

Comment: Try to set up your .env with credential of database. do you already set up it?

Comment: @SokChanty already done that..here's my .env

Comment: Can you check with log?

Comment: where can i check it again? is it in /var/log?

Comment: @SokChanty added the error log.

Comment: Try deleting the vendor folder and running composer install again

Comment: @apokryfos already tried that. but still no luck.

Comment: Try also deleting the package.lock file. Also try to backtrace where the call is coming from, for example if it's originating from a provider's `register` function there's a chance Laravel is not fully booted at that point

Comment: @apokryfos the error coming from model.php from the vendor folder. I really don't have any clue how to debug this. Tried removing the lock files but still not fixing it.

Comment: Normally no code should be directly calling Model.php, since that's a class only intended to be extended. If you do `php artisan cache:clear -vvv` it should increase the verbosity level of the error reporting and include stack trace of the entire call tree. If it doesn't work then (unfortunately) you'd need to modify the source and do a `dd(debug_backtrace())` before the line that errors to determine what first originates the call.

Comment: @apokryfos currently can't do any `php artisan`. It will return the `Call to a member function connection() on null` error. By source which file do I need to do the `dd(debug_backrace())` on?

Comment: @apokryfos I did the `dd(debug_backtrace())` and found out that my connection is null and there's no table. But I do have my .env file in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remember these steps and implement them step by step when you change the `.env` file.

1. Make sure to add database credentials in `.env`.
2. If you use Laravel's built-in server, I mean by the `php artisan serve` command, If you change your `.env` while the PHP server is running it's not gonna use the changed setting of the `.env` file until you disconnect the server once and run it again. Laravel reads the `.env` file once when it starts to run the PHP server. So any change during the server's running state may not affect the config setting until you rerun the PHP server.
3. If none of the above doesn't help you, Run `php artisan config:clear` once; To clear the config cache just in case of unwanted caching.

Comment: added database credentials in my `.env` but when I tried debugging it the connection return null..

Comment: @Daniel_C how do you run your laravel project?

Comment: Use php artisan serve..but whenever I tried to run any `php artisan` I'm getting the error above..

Comment: @Daniel_C did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Daniel_C check database.php config. can you name the  'connections' that you have in the config? if not msyql connection defined in the connections array you get this error. provide the mysql config if existed to check the problem.